# Add angularjs component via service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-components

I am trying to add angularjs component using the code as per below. `app.component` doesn't work like this

Where as if I execute `app.component` from outsite it works.

How to fix this issue. Notice that the API will return component names. I just need to render them.

```
app.service('applookup', function($http) {
    this.register = function() {

        return $http.get('http://localhost:3003/api/provider/fetch/app1').then(function(res){
            app.component('appleComponent', {
                template : 'test'
            });
            return res.data.componentList;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a new component dynamically depending on the response of a remote call? If that is the case I'd say that this post can help you. https://dpopescu.me/2016/02/29/dynamic-loading-of-angularjs-components/

Comment: http://www.sagarganatra.com/2014/08/lazy-loading-angularjs-components-using-providers.html could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @William and @Zooly mentioned in comments. We can add reference to `$compileProvider.component` as per below in `app.config`

```
app.register = {

component :  function(name, object) {
    $compileProvider.component(name, object);
return (this);
}
```

Then use `app.register.component` to register the component